# Server-side ajax search, wait till finish entering - Multi tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the following code:

```
$('.gerais').each(function(){
    var daotable = $(this).data('dao');
    x = $(this).DataTable({
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: $('body').data('url')+'gerais/ajax_list/'+daotable,
            type: "POST"
        },
        buttons: {            
            dom: {
                button: {
                    className: 'btn btn-default'
                }
            },
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'copyHtml5',
                    text: "<i class=' icon-copy3'></i> Copiar"
                },
                {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    text: "<i class=' icon-file-excel'></i> Excel"
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    text: "<i class=' icon-file-pdf'></i> PDF"
                },
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    text: '<i class="icon-printer"></i> Imprimir'
                }
            ],
        }
    });

});
$('.dataTables_filter input[type=search]').attr('placeholder','Pesquisar...')
.unbind()
.bind('input', function(e){
    var item = $(this);
    searchWait = 0;
    if(!searchWaitInterval) searchWaitInterval = setInterval(function(){
        if(searchWait >= 3){
            clearInterval(searchWaitInterval);
            searchWaitInterval = '';
            searchTerm = $(item).val();
            x[z].search(searchTerm).draw(); // change to new api
            searchWait = 0;
        }
        searchWait++;
    },200);

});
```

This part of the code is responsible for the loop that create data tables on my page, that have the class ".gerais":

```
$('.gerais').each(function(){
    var daotable = $(this).data('dao');
    x = $(this).DataTable({
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: $('body').data('url')+'gerais/ajax_list/'+daotable,
            type: "POST"
        },
        buttons: {            
            dom: {
                button: {
                    className: 'btn btn-default'
                }
            },
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'copyHtml5',
                    text: "<i class=' icon-copy3'></i> Copiar"
                },
                {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    text: "<i class=' icon-file-excel'></i> Excel"
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    text: "<i class=' icon-file-pdf'></i> PDF"
                },
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    text: '<i class="icon-printer"></i> Imprimir'
                }
            ],
        }
    });

});
```

And this one is responsible by the delay on the search

```
$('.dataTables_filter input[type=search]').attr('placeholder','Pesquisar...')
.unbind()
.bind('input', function(e){
    var item = $(this);
    searchWait = 0;
    if(!searchWaitInterval) searchWaitInterval = setInterval(function(){
        if(searchWait >= 3){
            clearInterval(searchWaitInterval);
            searchWaitInterval = '';
            searchTerm = $(item).val();
            x[z].search(searchTerm).draw(); // change to new api
            searchWait = 0;
        }
        searchWait++;
    },200);

});
```

This works well for just one table, but I have 3 tables and it only works on the last one.

I already tried to transform "x" on a array and it didn't work.

Comment: It's make in Datatables plugins

Comment: And i removed de "[z]" at "x[z].search(....."

Comment: "bind" has been deprecated.

Comment: Your use of x is wrong. Its a global variable that you are setting in each loop. Because of that, it will only "remember" the last table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some minor changes and tested it on two client side (serverSide:false) tables.

```
        $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
            $('#tblTab1').DataTable();
            $('#tblTab2').DataTable();

                // definded global variable.
                var searchWaitInterval = null;
            $('.dataTables_filter input[type=search]').attr('placeholder', 'Pesquisar...')
               .off()
               .on('input', function (e) {
                   var item = $(this);
                   var  searchWait = 0;
                   if (!searchWaitInterval) searchWaitInterval = setInterval(function () {
                      if (searchWait >= 3) {
                        clearInterval(searchWaitInterval);
                        searchWaitInterval = null;
                        searchTerm = $(item).val();
                          // aria-controls is an attribute added by DataTables so it makes it easy to target the right 
                          // tables without resorting to global variables.
                          $("#" + item.attr("aria-controls")).DataTable().search(searchTerm).draw(); // change to new api
                          searchWait = 0;
                }
                searchWait++;
            }, 200);

        });
    });
```

Comment: Having said that, using "input" event with the placeholder causes it to fire just by clicking on the field.  You will make an unnecessary trip to the server if the user clicks on the field but decides not to enter anything.  If you want to keep the placeholder, I recommend you change the event to "keypress".

Comment: i need the "each", because of some pages i have 6 tables, all of them make ajax request to get the info. And this permit me not have a js file with n rows that make the same thing. Do you know what i can do, for make this function work in this away?

Comment: I tested here and works, thanks a lot, for your help.